# Anaconda Navigator not working: ImportError: cannot import name '_psutil_windows'

Tags: python, anaconda

My system: Windows 7 professional, 64 bit

Things I have tried:

- Reinstalling Anaconda
- Made sure I only have one Python version installed (I have 3.6.4)
- Added Anaconda to PATH (%PATH;C:\Users\ghost\Anaconda3\python.exe)

system variables

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\ProgramData\Lenovo\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python;%PATH;C:\Users\ghost\Anaconda3\python.exe;C:\Users\ghost\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
```

The Error I receive:

```
   >      (base) C:\Users\ghost>anaconda-navigator Traceback (most recent call last):   File
    > "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line
    > 10,  in <module>
    >     sys.exit(main())   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.p
    > y", line 129, in main
    >     from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.
    > py", line 27, in <module>
    >     from anaconda_navigator.utils import misc   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\misc
    > .py", line 21, in <module>
    >     import psutil   File "C:\Users\ghost\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\psutil\__in
    > it__.py", line 137, in <module>
    >     from . import _pswindows as _psplatform   File "C:\Users\ghost\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\psutil\_psw
    > indows.py", line 16, in <module>
    >     from . import _psutil_windows as cext ImportError: cannot import name '_psutil_windows'
```

Let me know if there is any additional information that is needed. Thanks, in advance, for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Go to anaconda prompt, update `conda` and all packages and install the last version of `psutil`.

Then, from `C:\Users\<youruser>\Anaconda3\pkgs\psutil-5.4.5-py36hfa6e2cd_0\Lib\site-packages`, copy the folders `psutil` and `psutil-5.4.5-py3.6.egg-info`.

After that, go to `C:\Users\<youruser>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages`.

Erase all `psutil` folders and paste `psutil` and `psutil-5.4.5-py3.6.egg-info`.

You may also want to make sure that your `PYTHONPATH` is not set. You can see all of your relevant environment variables in the output of:

```
conda info -a
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me.  My Anaconda installation was in a different location, however: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3`. If you don't know the location of your Anaconda installation, you can type `where anaconda` at the Anaconda command prompt